# How to deploy Command Set Extension for Site Pages Library

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, sharepoint-framework, listviewcommandset

I would like to know how to specify location of ListViewCommandSet Extension in "Site Pages Library"
I have set `ListTemplateId="100"`to show in custom List View
and `ListTemplateId="101"` to show commandSet in Library in all my libraries
But nothing changed in "Site Pages"
How Could be possible to specify Content location to show Commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base Template ID for "Site Pages" library is 119 and not 101,

[image]

You check that on [Microsoft official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sharepoint_protocols/ms-wssts/8bf797af-288c-4a1d-a14b-cf5394e636cf)

Comment: it worked,now it's visible in Site Page Library after setting ListTemplateId="119" in element.xml